# Using the generic type 'List<T>' requires 1 type arguments" when argument is already given

Tags: c#, list

I keep getting this error for whenever I try to use `List.Count`, even when my list already has the argument `<int>`. Please help!

```
using Godot;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public override void _Ready()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int answer  = rnd.Next(1, 6);

    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    int num = 0;
    int TimesTried = 0;

    num = rnd.Next(1, 6);

    while (List.Count < 5) // NB - the error says the issue is here
        if (numbers.Contains(num) && TimesTried < 5)
        {
            num = rnd.Next(1, 6);
        }
        else
        {
            numbers.Add(num);

            if (TimesTried == 0){
                GetNode<Label>("../AnswerOption").Text = num.ToString();
            } else if (TimesTried == 1){
                GetNode<Label>("../OptionRandom1").Text = num.ToString();
            } else if (TimesTried == 2){
                GetNode<Label>("../OptionRandom2").Text = num.ToString();
            } else if (TimesTried == 3){
                GetNode<Label>("../OptionRandom3").Text = num.ToString();
            } else if (TimesTried == 4){
                GetNode<Label>("../OptionRandom4").Text = num.ToString();
            } 

            TimesTried = TimesTried + 1;
        }
```

Comment: List is a type, you meant while numbers.count?

Comment: You've written `List.Count` but what you actually want to do is to access the property `Count` of the concrete instance. So you have to write `numbers.Count` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numbers` is the instance of the `List<int>`. It should be `numbers.Count` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I was pulling my hair out at this small little mistake for ages!

Answer (score 1):

It should be `while (numbers.Count < 5)` .